# How to encode System.Drawing.Bitmap to CCITT with C#?

Tags: c#, pdf

I need to write a black and white image to a PDF file, so I thought the better way would be using CCITTDecode. The question is, how do I save my

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap img
```

to the file stream using the correct encoding algorithm? I tried with the following code

```
EncoderParameters eps = new EncoderParameters(1);

eps.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
ImageCodecInfo[] ie = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
ImageCodecInfo tiffEncoder = null;

for (int i = 0; i < ie.Length; i++)
{
    if (ie[i].MimeType == "image/tiff")
    {
        tiffEncoder = ie[i];
        break;
    }
}

img.Save(_stream, tiffEncoder, eps);
```

but the output is an entire TIFF file (header and other markers included). I need just the raw data, because the decoding parameters are provided in PDF.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Drawing.Bitmap` doesn't offer any means to save just raw data of an image.

I think you will be better served by some 3rd party libraries in this case. For example, you could try [LibTiff.Net](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) library (produced by my company). The library is free (commercial-friendly BSD license) open source software.

LibTiff.Net can encode System.Drawing.Bitmap using CCITT or you can open already encoded file. After that you can use [ReadRawStrip](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/api/BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.html#BitMiracle_LibTiff_Classic_Tiff_ReadRawStrip_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) and [ReadRawTile](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/api/BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Tiff.html#BitMiracle_LibTiff_Classic_Tiff_ReadRawTile_System_Int32_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) to access raw image data.

Here is a sample that might be useful for you:

- [Convert System.Drawing.Bitmap to a black and white TIFF](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/ImageToBitonalTiff)